# checking an entire ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple idea on my mind but I am not sure how to implement it properly...
Here's the deal:

Say there is an ArrayList called myList of size 5 and then there is
an Integer called testNumber. The values inside myList and/or testNumber are irrelevant.

What I need to do is compare the testNumber variable with each of myList's integers
and if testNumber doesn't equal to none of them, then perform an operation (i.e. `System.out.println("hi");`).

How should I go about it..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply do

```
if (!myList.contains(testNumber))
    System.out.println("no element equals " + testNumber);
```

Strictly speaking this probably doesn't *"compare each element to `testNumber`"*. So, if you're actually interested in the "manual" way of comparing each element, here's how:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i : myList) {
    if (i == testNumber)
        found = true;
}

if (!found)
    System.out.println("no element equals " + testNumber);
```

Comment: In fact, the `contains` method compares each element, until a fitting one is found. (It used the equals method instead of `==`, too.)

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList has a method called [contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) which is suitable for this task:

> Returns true if this list contains the
>   specified element. More formally,
>   returns true if and only if this list
>   contains at least one element e such
>   that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)).

You can use it as follow:

```
if(!myList.contains(testNumber)) {
   PerformOperation();
}
```

Comment: Don't write `... == false`, write `! ...`. For booleans `==` and `!=` are only sensible if both sides are not constant.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, Paulo! Edited!